# How to stop chrome from opening in a private window?

Tags: google-chrome, mac

I've recently noticed when I click any link from a Mac application (i.e click a link sent on the Slack desktop app or run a simple command like `open https://www.google.com`) Chrome will open in a private window (not incognito, but a default window signed out of my account and with no cache).

I'm wondering if anyone else has had this problem and has any ideas on how to fix it. I would prefer if clicking links opened a regular Chrome environment giving all the benefits of password completion and whatnot. Additionally, when this "private" Chrome opens and I try to sign in to my Google account in it I get the following error:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean `http` or is that a typo? http **is** insecure.

Comment: yes typo, fixed